# Gallery images should fill width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, gallery

Depending on the number of available pictures, i use an imageview or Gallery. When there is only one picture available, it uses the imageview and that works like a charm. I use a imageloader from the u[niversalloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/UniversalImageLoader/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core) . The picture is at the top of my screen in full width.

When there are multiple pictures i use a gallery, with pagerindicators. On smaller screens this works fine. But on tablets the picture doesnt fill the full screen, which is weird because the single imageview does, and the imageloader does its job perfect. I think it has something to do with my gallery settings.

code for the gallery:

```
// define pager identifier
        pager = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerdot1 =(ImageView)pager.findViewById(R.id.pager_dot_1);
        pagerdot2 =(ImageView)pager.findViewById(R.id.pager_dot_2);
        pagerdot3 =(ImageView)pager.findViewById(R.id.pager_dot_3);
        venueImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.venueImage);
        venueGallery = (CustomGallery)findViewById(R.id.GVvenueImage);


        imageLoader=new LargerImageLoader(this.getApplicationContext());



        if(venue.photos.size()>1){//multiple photos --> gallery

            if(venue.photos.size()==2){
                pagerdot3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            venueGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            venueImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String[] fotos = new String[venue.photos.size()]; 
            for(int i=0;i<venue.photos.size();i++){
                if(venue.photos.get(i).large !=null){
                    fotos[i] = venue.photos.get(i).large;
                    System.out.println(venue.photos.get(i).large);
                }
            }
            ImagePagerAdapter galleryad = new ImagePagerAdapter(fotos);

            venueGallery.setAdapter(galleryad);
            venueGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        pagerdot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_oranje);
                        pagerdot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        pagerdot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pagerdot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_oranje);
                        pagerdot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        pagerdot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pagerdot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_oranje);
                        pagerdot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        pagerdot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        break;
                    default:
                        pagerdot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_oranje);
                        pagerdot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                        pagerdot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pager_wit);
                    }


                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {

                }


            });
        }else if(venue.photos.size() ==1 ){ //1 foto
            if(venue.photos.get(0).large != null){
                venueGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                venueImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(venue.photos.get(0).large, venueImage);
            } else{
                setStandardPic();
            }
            pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //                
        } else{
            setStandardPic();           
        }
```

and with:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
        this.images = images;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = null;
        RelativeLayout borderImg;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height)); // size
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, parent, false);
            borderImg = new RelativeLayout(getBaseContext());
            borderImg.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            borderImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // no color
        }else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                    borderImg = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
                }

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(images[position], imageView);
        borderImg.addView(imageView);
        return borderImg;
    }
}
```

xml of top screen:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/venueImage"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:fadingEdge="none"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/header_food" />

                    <com.hera.ontdekdelft.lazyloader.CustomGallery
                        android:id="@+id/GVvenueImage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:fadingEdge="none"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/venueCategoryImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/venuecategory_sights" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        layout="@layout/gallery_pager" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

My custom gallery is just a normal gallery with the onFling method overriden for better fling settings.

What should i change to make my gallery work as well in tablet screens?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where your width and height are coming from in your source ...
I don't have a tablet, but this is working well on my galaxy note and the emulator. Your math for height may vary depending on the aspect ratio of your images.

screen_width and screen_height come in in the constructor for the adapter :

in main activity

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screen_width = size.x;
    screen_height = size.y;
```

adapter getview

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int postion, View view, ViewGroup group)
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);

            imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[postion]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(_screen_width, (int) ((double)_screen_height/2.5)));
            return imageView;
        }
```